# Combine grammar infix postfix prefix

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar, parser-generator, jflex

I'm writing some kind of calculator using Jflex and CUP, I was able to make my grammar for infix, postfix and prefix notation as seen below, they works well if I just use each grammar and don't combine them.

The problem now is how can I combine them without getting a reduce/shift error, I've been doing this a few days now and I can't really figure it out. The main problem is when F --> NUMBER and E --> NUMBER they will have a reduce/shift error, I also tried adding more rules to try to mitigate the reduce/shift error but I'm not getting it correctly. Take note also that I was able to combine any combination of two but not three of them.

One approach I did is to try to merge my prefix and postfix to my infix by changing E to T and creating a new Rule  T --> E|Number, but I still

It would be very helpful if someone could give me an explanation on how I can try to combine them.

Here is my Grammar

```
 /* INFIX */
   E --> E - T | E + T| T
   T --> T * F | T / F | F
   F --> NUMBER


/*PRE fix */
   E --> + E E | - E E | / E E | * E E | NUMBER


/*POST fix*/
   E --> E E + | E E -| E E * |E E / |NUMBER
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you're using java CUP from here, correct? http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/

Comment: yes that's what I'm using, I'm just showing my grammar, instead of the cup file, and I was able to get the correct grammar now, how can I answer my own question :)

Comment: You can just post an answer like you would to any other question, and then immediately accept it as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the grammar

> program -> infix | prefix | postfix
>
> infix -> E
>
> E -> E - T | E + T | T | T * F | T / F | F
>
> F -> (E) | n
>
> prefix -> Epre
>
> Epre ->  + Fpre Fpre | - Fpre Fpre | * Fpre Fpre | / Fpre Fpre
>
> Fpre -> Epre | n
>
> postfix -> Epost
>
> Epost -> Fpost Fpost + |  Fpost Fpost - | Fpost Fpost * | Fpost Fpost
>   /
>
> Fpost -> Epost | n